# pdfrw checkbox AS values gets unwanted parentheses

Tags: python, pdf, pdfrw

So I'm trying to mark checkboxes in a PDF file with pdfrw. That means changing the checkboxes "AS" value from the default "/Off" to "/Yes".
pdfrw is currently forcing parentheses around my "/Yes" when it writes to file, so it doesn't work. How do I keep it from adding these parentheses?

My code:

```
template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)
annotations = template_pdf.pages[0][/Annots]
for annotation in annotations:
    annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(AS="/Yes"))
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(output_pdf_path, template_pdf)
```

My checkboxes in the PDF-file ends up like this, first word in third line is the important one:

```
1661 0 obj
<</AP <</D <</Off 1845 0 R /Yes 1846 0 R>> /N <</Yes 1847 0 R>>>> /AS
    (/Yes) /F 4 /FT /Btn /MK <</CA (l)>> /P 1608 0 R /Rect
    [101.275 576.22 107.395 584.91] /Subtype /Widget /T (box1) /Type
    /Annot>>
endobj
```

But to make the check mark actually show up in most PDF-viewers it needs to be like this:

```
1661 0 obj
<</AP <</D <</Off 1845 0 R /Yes 1846 0 R>> /N <</Yes 1847 0 R>>>> /AS
    /Yes /F 4 /FT /Btn /MK <</CA (l)>> /P 1608 0 R /Rect
    [101.275 576.22 107.395 584.91] /Subtype /Widget /T (box1) /Type
    /Annot>>
endobj
```

I could always just open the file in python and just replace all the instances of "(/Yes)" with "/Yes", but there has to be some way to get the right values with pdfrw.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you might need to use `PdfName('Yes')` instead of `"/Yes"`:

```
annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(AS=pdfrw.PdfName('Yes')))
```

I didn't test this. But it works.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: pdfrw.PdfDict(V=pdfrw.PdfName('On')) worked for me.

Comment: The `()` wrapper indicates a PDF String, but you needed a PDF Name.  I'd have been shocked if this didn't work.  One of the things that most vexed me in the PDF standard was that while both String and Name have numeric escape sequences, in String the escapes were in hexadecimal, while names use... *octal*?  Just pick one already.  (but it's far to late to change now).  IIRC, "Names" are hashed, while strings are kept as character strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(V=pdfrw.PdfName('On')))
```

Above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
template.Root.Pages.Kids[0].Annots[0].update(PdfDict(AS=PdfName('On'), V=PdfName('On')))
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation .

Comment: `template = PdfReader(TEMPLATE_PATH_AND_FILENAME)
template.Root.Pages.Kids[0].Annots[0].update(PdfDict(AS=PdfName('On'), V=PdfName('On')))`

remember. this is indexed. you should know your page index and the annotation index.